# uploaded image doesn't change in the browser, although on the drive I have the new image

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a View where I can upload an image and the image is also displayed in there like this:

```
//ResourceStorage is a virtual directory that indicates to the pictures storage location
    <img src='<%=Url.Content("~/ResourceStorage/Profile/pic.jpg") %>' alt='pic' />
```

after I upload the picture, on the hard drive I get the new **"pic.jpg"** but in the browser I still have the old one (I tried clearing the cache, doesn't help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying this in IIS or on your local Cassini development server?

Try this:

[IIS 7 Force Fresh Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930914/iis-7-force-fresh-images)

Comment: I'm doing it on IIS, and I just fixed it, [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)] helped, don't know if this is the best solution though

Comment: If it is a static resource, then it is best that IIS cache it on your production server.

Comment: and on Internet Explorer I still have to hit refresh once to get it right