# ASP.net web page still displaying cached versions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IIS 7 Force Fresh Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930914/iis-7-force-fresh-images)

My web page is still displaying a previously cached versions of the page.

I have this in the page_load event:

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Expires = -1;
    Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

I have this in the Page_Init:

```
protected void Page_Init(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
}
```

Any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime you need to flush the browser. If you use IE, the tool that helps is the IE Toolbar for Developers with Fiddler.

For firefox use Firebug with Fiddler.