# Why is caching such an issue in .net 3.5?

Tags: .net-3.5, caching, internet-explorer-8

Has anyone else having an issue with browser caching when using .net?
I am using VS 2008 and IE8. And I include [all the recommended code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760732/asp-net-web-page-still-displaying-cached-versions)
to ensure that there is no caching, still 20% of the time, I get cached values. This was never an issue with classic asp. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "include all recommended code"?

Comment: like the code on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760732/asp-net-web-page-still-displaying-cached-versions

Comment: Please use a web debugger (e.g. Fiddler) to capture your HTTP Response headers, and post them here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insure you get fresh results, append a nonce to the query string, or, if there is no query string, introduce one, that contains a nonce.

Instead of requesting `http://foo/bar.htm` , request `http://foo/bar.htm?_=4944994230`.

This works with static content or dynamically-generated content. You can name the parameter anything. In this case I just used an underscore. Just be careful to not duplicate the name of a querystring param that is used by the actual application.

To make it transparent, you can do this in browser-script, in the click event of a button before submitting a form. 
This is how jQuery implements its "do not use cache" option for ajax requests.