# Pivotviewer showing cached images

Tags: silverlight, pivotviewer

I am making Silverlight 5 application using pivotviewer, trying to load images in pivotviewer which are received from server. Now pivotviewer is showing old cached images.

DZI images at the server side has already refreshed.

How to remove the cached images shown by pivotviewer.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Tom

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are talking about a browser refresh (or something similiar) is still pulling the old cached images from a previous deep zoom collection?  If so, this is an IIS setting (or more correctly a web server issue).

Take a look here for how to disable caching : [IIS 7 Force Fresh Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930914/iis-7-force-fresh-images)

If you are having a different issue, please let me know.

Comment: Tony's comment is exactl right. I just turned off all caching for the directory that I was serving these things from. For whatever reason, when the Silverlight control does fetching it doesn't know the page has been refreshed, so it doesn't re-fetch everything.